# Multithreading start method

Tags: java, multithreading

[image: Thread explained]

and this a normal thread program

```
class Counter implements Runnable {
    private int currentValue;
    public Counter() { currentValue = 0; }
    public int getValue() { return currentValue; }
    public void run() { // (1) Thread entry point
    try {
      while (currentValue < 5) {
      System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " + (currentValue++)); // (2) Print thread name.
     Thread.sleep(250); // (3) Current thread sleeps.
          }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " interrupted.");
           }
           System.out.println("Exit from thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
         }
      }

 //_______________________________________________________________________________
public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Counter counterA = new Counter(); // (4) Create a counter.
    Thread worker = new Thread(counterA, "Counter A");// (5) Create a new thread.
    System.out.println(worker);
    worker.start(); // (6) Start the thread.
    try {
       int val;
       do {
         val = counterA.getValue(); // (7) Access the counter value.
         System.out.println("Counter value read by " + Thread.currentThread().getName()+ ": " + val); // (8) Print thread name.
         Thread.sleep(1000); // (9) Current thread sleeps.
           } while (val < 5);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          System.out.println("The main thread is interrupted.");
       }
       System.out.println("Exit from main() method.");
     }
    }
```

and the output is

```
Thread[Counter A,5,main]
Counter value read by main thread: 0
Counter A: 0
Counter A: 1
Counter A: 2
Counter A: 3
Counter value read by main thread: 4
Counter A: 4
Exit from thread: Counter A
Counter value read by main thread: 5
Exit from main() method.
```

My question is even though the worker thread was started initially before the Main thread enters it's try block, Main thread execution starts first and then when the Main thread goes to sleep child thread gets into action.

As this picture(taken from "A Programmer's Guide To Java SCJP Certification : A Comprehensive Primer 3rd Edition"
Author: Khalid A Mughal, Rolf W Rasmussen) depicts that when the start method is called on the thread it returns immediately.

Please explain this point that why on invoking start method it return immediately and does the thread get starts on calling the start method. As here on calling the start method it doesn't invoke run method of the class. So when does actually the thread starts ?

Also explain this " the call to the start() method is asynchronous."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are three things that you are missing in your overall analysis.

1. Call to thread's start method is sequential not parallel. Its the call to run method of Thread that is concurrent. So if you have 5 statements in main method that call start, the 5ht is not going t be called first. Thats the 'happens before' guarantee that JVM specs give you. However the run method of 1 first may get called before or after the call to the second start statement. This depends as its more of a CPU time slicing issue rather than program execution.
2. When more than 1 thread runs in your program the order of output is in-deterministic. That's because they run in parallel. You can never be sure that the same program will run in same order on two machines or even in two runs on the same machine. In your question you have posted only 1 output. Run the program like 20 times one after another and match the output. I am sure 2 or 3 would be entirely different.
3. Finally, you are basing your analysis on the order or execution of your concurrent code. That's the biggest blooper programmer make. Concurrent programs are never intended to run in a specific order or sequence. Just try to make your Runnable work an atomic mutually exclusive task (mutually exclusive to the rest of program or even to other Runnables) and track its own execution. Dont mix Threads together.

Comment: I have read these things and I know that concurrent code are not meant to run in specific order.

Regarding your 2nd point. Forget about 20, I have run this 100 times and I got the same output on the same machine.

And I agree that output may differ in on different machine. But that's not my question.

And I am just asking how does the start method works..!

Comment: The output is the same because with this number of operations and with them taking so little time it's almost deterministic. To get actually different results you would need to run it on different machines with different loads

Comment: sometimes on windows/linux a specific order of execution sticks. try to get some heavy load on your system and the try running your code multiple times. Start will always be executed sequentially. But once start finishes (Your new thread is created and has a separate execution stack now) your new thread may directly go into Runnable state or not. That depends on your system. Run will always run concurrently.

Comment: try running the loop for say 1 million hops and sleeping for say 2 ms in between.

Comment: All I am asking is that when start method is invoked does it wait for thread to create and then goes into it's run method or rather it returns to the main thread and wait until the thread is created and then call the run method.

Comment: start method is invoked by the main thread. So obviously it will return to next statement in main after start finishes. start is not executed by your new Thread. That is what it means when we say "start is executed sequentially?

Comment: And yeah..! I am learning all these things just because my test requires to me answer these silly codes which can even differ on platform and even on different circumstances. I know this is not the way you would code if you want something in the order you want.!

Comment: No its true. Concurrency is one of the most powerful features in Java. Like i said in my point 3 above, all you need to ensure that your Thread's run or the Runnable implementation works on an atomic piece or task that is mutually exclusive to the rest of your code logic and you would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly enforce which Thread is executed/running when. Once you start it, it's handled on lower level(usually by OS) and the results may differ on different machine or even in different execution. If you need more control, you need to use some synchronization mechanism.

Comment: Once I start it return immediately to Main thread, that's what we can see in the Output.

Answer (score 1):

The thread is isn't started synchronously underneath the call to `start()`. It happens later (asynchronously). In other words, just because you called `start()` doesn't mean the thread has started.

They why and how are all implementation details, that may depend on JVM and/or OS implementations.

Comment: Then what actually happens. When I call start method it comes back to the Main thread, and it goes on to execute it's statement.

Comment: "It happens later (asynchronously)."

When does it happen ? As theory tells that when you invoke the start method on thread it executes the run() method of the Runnable object.

Comment: @user2963317 It does much more than that! For once - it would actually create an OS thread, that does not happen instantly (or reuse a thread, depends on the JVM etc). When you call start the actual creation of the thread is started, and when it's done the run is called. As you can see in the picture you posted, when run is invoked is independent of what happens in the original thread (that called start). In your case, since your ops are all lightweight Main gets to do some more OPs before run is invoked

Comment: Ahh..! That means it isn't necessary that very time the start method is called on Thread it return to the Thread which started it(here which is Main Thread), rather it can invoke run method directly without returning to the Thread which started it(here which is Main Thread)